# The mobile app property in google analytics tuns out web app

Tags: google-analytics

When I make mobile app property, it turns out app + web instantly!

I don't know why. Is there any permission to make app only? There is no problem to make web property, app + web.

I just want get a tracking code for iOS but it is impossible from app + web.

[image: select mobile app property. Not app + web]

[image: insert property name.]

[image: and it is app + web now.]

Comment: You will need to use Firebase SDKs. They began sunsetting the GA Service SDKs in Oct and existing Mobile App Properties stopped collecting data as of Oct 31.  https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9167112

Comment: @BronwynV OMG! Thank you very much! I never think of that happend. that google :( Can I do something for you? like select answer? can I do that to comment?

Comment: It has caused a lot of confusion for ppl. I've added it as an answer to your question so it can be selected as answer :-) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use Firebase SDKs.
They began sunsetting the GA Service SDKs in Oct and existing Mobile App Properties stopped collecting data as of Oct 31.
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9167112
eta.. you can use the app + web property and create an iOS data stream and link it to the Firebase project. Keep in mind though the app + web property is still in beta and not really ready for a production environment at this stage.